# Lebesgue integral on given set

Tags: integration, analysis

i´d like to calculate the following integral 
$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^3}}\chi_B\,d\cal L^3 $with lebesgue measure on the set $B:= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: 0≤y≤x\sqrt{3}\,,0≤z≤2\,,1≤x^2+y^2≤4\}$
and $\chi_B$ is defined as follows

$\chi_B:=\begin{cases} 0,\, x\not\in B \\ 1,\,x\in B \end{cases}$

I´d like to do it with cylinder coordinates

$x=r\cdot cos(\varphi)\\y=r\cdot sin(\varphi) \\ z=z$

i have tried it by my own but i can't find the right limits for the transformation.

can someone tell me the right limits and how to get them please ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, notice that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^3}}\chi_B\,d\cal L^3$ = $\int\limits_{B}d\cal L^3$.

You have the correct transformation. To find the limits:
Put $x=r\cdot \cos{(\phi)}$, $y=r\cdot \sin{(\phi)}$ in $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4$. You get: $1\leq r^2\leq 4$. Hence, $1\leq r\leq 2$. Now, with $0\leq y\leq \sqrt{3}x$ you get with the transformation the following: 
$$
0\leq r\sin{(\phi)}\leq \sqrt{3}r \cos{(\phi)}
$$ 
Dividing by $r\cos{(\phi)}$ yields
$$
0\leq \tan{(\phi)}\leq \sqrt{3}
$$
Hence, $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/3$. Now, we have
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_1^2r\,drd\phi dz=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \int_0^2\int_0^{\pi/3}d\phi dz= \frac{3}{2} \frac{\pi}{3}2 = \pi.
$$
Best regards,
serdar

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: you are welcome